# Number format displayed differently in the formula bar and cell vba

Tags: vba, excel, vb6

I used `ActiveCell.Numerformat= "(0)"` . The value is displayed with brackets in the cell but the formula bar shows the value without brackets.

Because of the above problem, Instead  of using Numberformat I appended the number with brackets

```
var= "(" & value & ")"
```

After writing the var to the cell it is displayed as -450 instead of (450)

Either of method does not work for me. Any help? I am confused with vba and excel formats.

Comment: 0 is the same as (0). The formula bar shows the actual value, not the formatted value.

Comment: If you always want parens around your numbers, then use a cell format, as you'd done with `NumberFormat`.. There's no need to add _more_ parens when you assign the cell value.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Sub Macro2()
    ActiveCell.NumberFormat = """(""General"")"""
End Sub
```

or:

```
Sub Macro2()
    ActiveCell.NumberFormat = """(""0"")"""
End Sub
```

Comment: No both work similar to   ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "(0)"